# ModelForm saving over model data with empty fields

Tags: python, django

I'm building an Edit form for a model in my database using a `ModelForm` in Django. Each field in the form is optional as the user may want to only edit one field.

The problem I am having is that when I call `save()` in the view, any empty fields are being saved over the instance's original values (e.g. if I only enter a new `first_name`, the `last_name` and `ecf_code` fields will save an empty string in the corresponding instance.)

The form:

```
class EditPlayerForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Player
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'ecf_code']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EditPlayerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['first_name'].required = False
        self.fields['last_name'].required = False
        self.fields['ecf_code'].required = False
```

The view:

```
def view(request, player_pk = ''):

    edit_player_form = forms.EditPlayerForm(auto_id="edit_%s")

    if "edit_player_form" in request.POST:

        if not player_pk:

            messages.error(request, "No player pk given.")

        else:

            try:

                selected_player = Player.objects.get(pk = player_pk)

            except Player.DoesNotExist:

                messages.error(request, "The selected player could not be found in the database.")
                return redirect("players:management")

            else:

                edit_player_form = forms.EditPlayerForm(
                    request.POST,
                    instance = selected_player
                )

                if edit_player_form.is_valid():

                    player = edit_player_form.save()
                    messages.success(request, "The changes were made successfully.")
                    return redirect("players:management")

                else:
                    form_errors.convert_form_errors_to_messages(edit_player_form, request)

    return render(
        request,
        "players/playerManagement.html",
        {
            "edit_player_form": edit_player_form,
            "players": Player.objects.all(),
        }
    )
```

I've tried overriding the `save()` method of the form to explicitly check which fields have values in the `POST` request but that didn't seem to make any difference either.

Attempt at overriding the save method:

```
def save(self, commit = True):

    # Tried this way to get instance as well
    # instance = super(EditPlayerForm, self).save(commit = False)

    self.cleaned_data = dict([ (k,v) for k,v in self.cleaned_data.items() if v != "" ])

    try:
        self.instance.first_name = self.cleaned_data["first_name"]
    except KeyError:
        pass

    try:
        self.instance.last_name = self.cleaned_data["last_name"]
    except KeyError:
        pass

    try:
        self.instance.ecf_code = self.cleaned_data["ecf_code"]
    except KeyError:
        pass


    if commit:
        self.instance.save()


    return self.instance
```

I also do not have any default values for the `Player` model as the docs say the `ModeForm` will use these for values absent in the form submission.

EDIT:

Here is the whole `EditPlayerForm`:

```
class EditPlayerForm(forms.ModelForm):


    class Meta:
        model = Player
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'ecf_code']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EditPlayerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['first_name'].required = False
        self.fields['last_name'].required = False
        self.fields['ecf_code'].required = False


    def save(self, commit = True):

        # If I print instance variables here they've already
        # been updated with the form values

        self.cleaned_data = [ k for k,v in self.cleaned_data.items() if v ]

        self.instance.save(update_fields = self.cleaned_data)

        if commit:

            self.instance.save()

        return self.instance
```

EDIT:

Ok so here is the solution, I figured I'd put it here as it might be useful to other people (I've certainly learned a bit from this).

So it turns out that the `is_valid()` method of the model form actually makes the changes to the instance you pass into the form, ready for the `save()` method to save them. So in order to fix this problem, I extended the `clean()` method of the form:

```
 def clean(self):

    if not self.cleaned_data.get("first_name"):
        self.cleaned_data["first_name"] = self.instance.first_name

    if not self.cleaned_data.get("last_name"):
        self.cleaned_data["last_name"] = self.instance.last_name

    if not self.cleaned_data.get("ecf_code"):
        self.cleaned_data["ecf_code"] = self.instance.ecf_code
```

This basically just checks to see if the fields are empty and if a field is empty, fill it with the existing value from the given instance. `clean()` gets called before the instance variables are set with the new form values, so this way, any empty fields were actually filled with the corresponding existing instance data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could maybe use the `update()` method instead of `save()`
or the argument  [update_field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#specifying-which-fields-to-save)

```
self.instance.save(update_fields=['fields_to_update'])
```

by building the list `['fields_to_update']` only with the not empty values.

It should even work with the comprehension you've tried :

```
self.cleaned_data = [ k for k,v in self.cleaned_data.items() if v ]

self.instance.save(update_fields=self.cleaned_data)
```

**EDIT :**

Without overriding the save method (and commenting out this attempt in the form):

```
not_empty_data = [ k for k,v in edit_player_form.cleaned_data.items() if v ]
print(not_empty_data)
player = edit_player_form.save(update_fields=not_empty_data)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! I've put this into the form's `save()` method, but its still not working, if I print the instance's variables at the start of the save method in the form, they've already been set to the empty string values before `instance.save()` is even called in the form's method (hope that made sense)

Comment: @RHSmith159 sorry this was not helping you,  could you add the form `EditPlayerForm` to the question ?

Comment: sure thing, I'll add it now

Comment: @RHSmith159  can you try the edit (inside the view)? not very sure why the fields are already saved in the form

Comment: So I've done a bit of digging around this morning, it looks like the instances variables are being set as soon as the form validation happens, once I call `is_valid()` in the view, it seems that the instance variables have all been set by the form. I'll let you know if I figure this out, its bugging me now haha
Thank you for all your help on this! :)

Comment: Got It! I'll edit my question with the solution. Thanks again for the help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: @RHSmith159 wow nice ! you should better post an answer and accept it to make it clear for next visitors !

Answer (score 1):

You could check the values if it's not empty in your view without overriding `save()`

```
if edit_player_form.is_valid():
    if edit_player_form.cleaned_data["first_name"]:
        selected_player.first_name = edit_player_form.cleaned_data["first_name"]
    if edit_player_form.cleaned_data["last_name"]:
        selected_player.last_name= edit_player_form.cleaned_data["last_name"]
    if edit_player_form.cleaned_data["ecf_code"]:
        selected_player.ecf_code= edit_player_form.cleaned_data["ecf_code"]
    selected_player.save()
```

This should work fine with what you want. I'm not sure if it's the best way to do it but it should work fine.